# How to print a text notification beside prime fibonacci numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, primes, fibonacci

This is an assignment from a grade 12 computer science class.

The section of the assignment I am having difficulty with reads as follows:

- Determine which of the first 20 Fibonacci numbers are prime numbers.
- **Put a “this is a prime” text notification in the printout from the Basic challenge.**
- Store the FibPrimes in an array called FibPrimes.

Here is what I have attempted:

Near the bottom, I attempted to make a loop that would print the text notification "This is a prime" if the given FibNum element was equal to a FibPrime element. This did not work. **The problem block is identified with a comment.** The rest of the program is okay.

```
package fibonaccinumbers;

public class FibonacciNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creation of Fibonacci Numbers Array.
       int [] FibNums = new int[20];
        FibNums[0] = 0;
        FibNums[1] = 1;

        // Creation if Fibonacci Primes Array.
        int [] FibPrimes = new int[7];
        FibPrimes[0] =  2;
        FibPrimes[1] =  3;
        FibPrimes[2] =  5;
        FibPrimes[3] =  13;
        FibPrimes[4] =  89;
        FibPrimes[5] =  233;
        FibPrimes[6] =  1597;

        // Printing first two fibonacci numbers.
        System.out.println(0);
        System.out.println(1 + "*");

        // Printing remaining fibonacci numbers up to 20th term.
        for (int i=2; i<FibNums.length;i++){ // Begin number generation loop.
            FibNums[i] = FibNums[i-1] + FibNums[i-2];

            // Checks if the fibonacci number is odd.
            // A number is not odd if two divides into it evenly.
            boolean oddcheck = true;
            if (FibNums[i]%2==0){
                oddcheck = false;
            }

            // Prints odd fibonacci numbers with a star beside it.
            // Prints even fibonacci numbers with no star beside it.
            if (oddcheck == true){
            System.out.println(FibNums[i] + "*");
            } else {
            System.out.println(FibNums[i]);    
            }

            // PROBLEM BLOCK HERE. ************************
            // If any element in the FibPrimes array is equal to the FibNums 
            // array, then the number is a prime.
            for (int n=0; n<=FibPrimes.length; n++){
                if (FibNums[i] == FibPrimes[n]){
                    System.out.print(" " + "This is a prime.");
                }
            }


        } // End number generation loop.

    }

}
```

Output with problem block removed:

```
0
1*
1*
2
3*
5*
8
13*
21*
34
55*
89*
144
233*
377*
610
987*
1597*
2584
4181*
```

(The stars identify odd numbers - from a different section of the assignment)

Output with problem block remaining:

```
0
1*
1*
```

Notice that the rest of the numbers do not print and there is no text notification.

There are likely better ways to solve the problem than I currently have, but I will continue to revise this. Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you.

Thank you @AJNeufeld and @YayPawSi. Using your solutions, I was able to make the program print. 
Revised Output:

```
0
1*
1*
This is a prime. 2
This is a prime. 3*
This is a prime. 5*
8
This is a prime. 13*
21*
34
55*
This is a prime. 89*
144
This is a prime. 233*
377*
610
987*
This is a prime. 1597*
2584
4181*
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   At a guess, I’d say your program is probably crashing with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` due to looping `for(int n=0; n <= FibPrimes.length; n++)`.  The last iteration indexes beyond the end of the array.

Comment: I am pretty sure that your assignment does not expect you to work out the prime fibonacii number beforehand and store them array (like you have done).  I'm pretty sure you are supposed to *calculate* whether a fibonacii number is prime, and store it in FibPrimes if it is.

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for this comment. You are definitely correct, I think so too. Due to difficulty with the assignment, my first priority was to create something "functioning". This will be my next goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException,

```
    //Remove = sign for n < FibPrimes.length
    for (int n = 0; n < FibPrimes.length; n++){
            if (FibNums[i] == FibPrimes[n]){
                System.out.print(" " + "This is a prime.");
            }
     }
```