# How to calculate prime fibonacci numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, primes, fibonacci

(This is an extension from my previous question).

[How to print a text notification beside prime fibonacci numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996036/how-to-print-a-text-notification-beside-prime-fibonacci-numbers)

### Task:

The section of the assignment I am having difficulty with reads as follows:

- **Determine which of the first 20 Fibonacci numbers are prime numbers.**
- Put a “this is a prime” text notification in the printout from the Basic challenge.
- **Store the FibPrimes in an array called FibPrimes.**

### Problem:

I cannot seem to figure out how to take each individual fibonacci number, determine it is prime, put the prime fibonacci numbers in an array, and print the output. I was able to make a working program previously, but I didn't use code to calculate the primes, I manually entered them into an array (see previous attempt at bottom).

### Attempt:

Here is what I have attempted:

**The code that is relevant to this question is emphasized with comments.**

```
package fibonaccinumbers;

public class FibonacciNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Creation of Fibonacci Numbers Array.
        // Let i represent the index number.
       int [] FibNums = new int[20];
        FibNums[0] = 0;
        FibNums[1] = 1;

        // Will add on each successive FibNums.
        // Will be used to calculate average.
        int FibSum = 1;

        // RELEVANT TO QUESTION.
        // Creation if Fibonacci Primes Array.
        // Let n represent the index number.
        int [] FibPrimes = new int[7];
        int n=0;

        // Printing first two fibonacci numbers.
        System.out.println(0);
        System.out.println(1 + "*");

        // Printing remaining fibonacci numbers up to 20th term.
        for (int i=2; i<FibNums.length;i++){ // Begin number generation loop.
            FibNums[i] = FibNums[i-1] + FibNums[i-2];

            // Checks if the fibonacci number is odd.
            // A number is not odd if two divides into it evenly.
            boolean oddcheck = true;
            if (FibNums[i]%2==0){
                oddcheck = false;
            }

            // RELEVANT TO QUESTION.
            // A prime number can only be divided by 1 and inself.
            // Divide FibNums[i] by every number inbetween.
            // If a number divides evenly, it is not a prime (exception: 2). 
            // Else, the number is a prime.
            boolean primecheck;
            for (int divisor = 2; divisor < FibNums[i]/2; divisor++){
                if (FibNums[i] % divisor == 0){
                    primecheck = false;
                } else {
                    primecheck = true;
                }

            // REVELANT TO QUESTION.
            // Add FibNums[i] to the FibPrimes[n] array if it is a prime.
            if (primecheck == false){
                FibPrimes[n] = FibNums[i];
                n = n + 1;
            }

            // RELEVANT TO QUESTION.
            // If any element in the FibPrimes array is equal to the FibNums 
            // array, then the number is a prime.
            for (n=0; n<FibPrimes.length; n++){
                if (FibNums[i] == FibPrimes[n]){
                    System.out.print("This is a prime." + " ");
                }
            }

            // Prints odd fibonacci numbers with a star beside it.
            // Prints even fibonacci numbers with no star beside it.
            if (oddcheck == true){
            System.out.println(FibNums[i] + "*");
            } else {
            System.out.println(FibNums[i]);    
            }

            FibSum = FibSum + FibNums[i];

        } // End number generation loop.

        System.out.print ( "The average is" + " " + FibSum/20);

    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
0
1*
The average is 0The average is 0The average is 0The average is 0This is a prime. 8
This is a prime. 8
The average is 013*
13*
13*
13*
The average is 321*
```

This is incorrect.

### Previous Attempt:

This solution "worked", but in order to not take the "lazy route" I must do the calculations using code. Only relevant snippets are shown:

```
// Creation if Fibonacci Primes Array.
// Ideally, this should be caulculated.
int [] FibPrimes = new int[7];
FibPrimes[0] =  2;
FibPrimes[1] =  3;
FibPrimes[2] =  5;
FibPrimes[3] =  13;
FibPrimes[4] =  89;
FibPrimes[5] =  233;
FibPrimes[6] =  1597;

    // If any element in the FibPrimes array is equal to the FibNums 
    // array, then the number is a prime.
    for (int n=0; n<FibPrimes.length; n++){
        if (FibNums[i] == FibPrimes[n]){
            System.out.print("This is a prime." + " ");
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
0
1*
1*
This is a prime. 2
This is a prime. 3*
This is a prime. 5*
8
This is a prime. 13*
21*
34
55*
This is a prime. 89*
144
This is a prime. 233*
377*
610
987*
This is a prime. 1597*
2584
4181*
The average is 547
```

**This is the desired output!** However, I cannot use this because I must calculate the prime fibonacci numbers using code. This is the "lazy route".

Thank you.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just make 2 parts, one that generates the first n-fibonacci numbers [(examples)](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Java) and then a separate piece of code that tests for whether it is prime [(examples)](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Primality_by_trial_division#Java). After you have these 2 pieces it should be straight forward.

Comment: Set `primecheck = true` at the start of the loop across potential divisors.  Currently, you're setting it to true whenever you find a number that's not a divisor.  You don't want to do that, otherwise lots of things will come out prime.

Comment: Very nicely compiled question. Everything is on point. As @Work mentioned you can create two methods that check for next Fibonacci number and another one for checking whether it is prime

Comment: @JoeC I'm sorry for the unclear submission. Thank you for your feedback and honesty. I included an abundance of code to ensure I didn't miss anything. I have read your attached link. I will leave current code (unsure which parts to delete). I will attempt to be more minimal in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just 10 mins on google and you will be able to create something simple and fast.

Using the mathematical formulas below :

[image]

which you can find more one this [paper](http://math.arizona.edu/~ura-reports/071/Campbell.Charles/Final.pdf) you can make your prime fibonacci sequence. In addition you will need a way to check which numbers in the sequence are primes so a quick way is through [AKS algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)

Here is a full example of all the above :

```
public class FibonacciSequence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            int num = (int) ((getY_1(i) - getY_2(i)) / Math.sqrt(5));
            if (isPrime(num)) {
                System.out.print("This is a prime : ");
            }
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }

    public static double getY_1(int N) {
        return Math.pow((1 + Math.sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0, N);
    }

    public static double getY_2(int N) {
        return Math.pow((1 - Math.sqrt(5.0)) / 2.0, N);
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
        if (num == 2 || num == 3)
            return true;

        if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        int i = 5;
        int s = 2;

        while (i * i <= num) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            i += s;
            s = 6 - s;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Of course you can exclude the value (1) if you don't feel like identifying it as a prime :P.

**Output :**

```
This is a prime : 1
This is a prime : 1
This is a prime : 2
This is a prime : 3
This is a prime : 5
8
This is a prime : 13
21
34
55
This is a prime : 89
144
This is a prime : 233
377
610
987
This is a prime : 1597
2584
4181
6765
```

P.S : I had free time :P

Comment: This is an amazing solution. You've managed to complete in a minimal amount of time what I've been trying for over a week. I appreciate you taking the time to submit this. I will take the time to process and understand the material presented.

Comment: @SydneyPerrin: Note that this *might* still be considered the lazy way. I suspect you are supposed to take advantage of some of the [divisibility relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Primes_and_divisibility) for fibonacci numbers to find primes amongst them.

Comment: @JamesKPolk This is helpful.

Comment: 1 is not a prime number